# easymock set expectations on parameters of a method of a mocked object

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I'm not sure how to set up this sort of behaviour with easymock. To illustrate I created a simplified example.
Basically, I have a method that returns void, and take one map, and I'd like easymock to change the map, deleting the entry that I specify.

Suppose I have the following interface:

```
public interface Filter{
    public void filter(Map<String,String>map);    

}
```

and the following class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Filter filter;
    public MyClass(Filter filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }
    public Map<String,String> process(Map<String,String>map) {
       filter.filter(map);
       return map;
    }
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to set this behaviour:

```
public class MyClassTest {

    /**
     * Test method for {@link easy.MyClass#process(java.util.Map)}.
     */
    @Test
    public void testProcess() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("one","AAA");
        map.put("remove","BBB");
        map.put("three","CCC");
        Map<String, String> expectedRet = new HashMap<String, String>();
        expectedRet.put("one","AAA");
        expectedRet.put("three","CCC");


        IMocksControl mockery = EasyMock.createControl();
        mockery.resetToStrict();
        mockery.checkOrder(true);

        Filter mockFilter = mockery.createMock("filter", Filter.class);
        MyClass m = new MyClass(mockFilter);
        mockFilter.filter(map);
        // I would like some behaviour that will remove the entry ("remove","BBB")
        // how can I define that?

        mockery.replay();
        m.process(map);        
        mockery.verify();

        assertEquals(expectedRet,map);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set an expectation that `m.process(map)` will call `filter(map)` on the mocked Filter:

```
    Filter mockFilter = mockery.createMock("filter", Filter.class);

    // set expectation
    mockFilter.filter(map);
    replay(mockFilter);

    MyClass m = new MyClass(mockFilter);
    m.process(map);

    // verify expectation
    verify(mockFilter);
```

The path you've taken in your code excerpt above is trying to verify your mocked filter. That shouldn't be the aim of your test. The class under test in your case is `MyClass`, not `Filter`.

**Update:** You can add behaviour to your mock:

```
expect(mockFilter.filter(map)).andDelegateTo(new Filter {
    @Override
    void filter(Map<String, String> map) {
        map.remove("remove");
    }
});
```

However, in your particular case the `Filter` interface is simple enough to cause `andDelegateTo` beat the purpose of using a mock `Filter` in the first place. With the same amount of code, you can use a concrete `Filter` instance in your test:

```
class TestFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    void filter(Map<String, String> map) {
        map.remove("remove");
    }
}

MyClass m = new MyClass(new TestFilter());
m.process(map);
assertNull(map.get("remove"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get your point, 1- mockFilter does not have a method called process(Map<String,String>) and then 2- where do you set the expectations that the map needs to be striped of an entry. could you clarify please?

Comment: @Charbel: (1) My mistake. I wrote `process(map)` instead of `filter(map)` while setting the expectation. The mocked `Filter` object will have a `filter` method. (2) That's the thing. You don't need to set the expectation that the filter will ultimately strip an entry. That's the concern for another test, where the class under test is `Filter`. In this test, we're testing `MyClass`. A test should ideally focus on one thing at a time.

Comment: Basically I want to test that whatever map is returned by filter. MyClass.process is not going to changed it.

Comment: @Charbel: Look up `andDelegateTo` in EasyMock documentation. You can add behaviour to your mock to act on the passed in map.